# DFPWM Audio file format structure

Tags: audio, format

I'm going to write a wav to dfpwm converter in lua. This is needed to play music in the minecraft game using the computronics mod. The bottom line is that I never managed to find any worthwhile information about this format, since it is very unpopular. All I could find is a brief description [here][1].

I also tried to learn about this format by reading the source code of the existing [LionRay converter][2]
But I do not know the java language at all and could not figure out how it works.

What I need is to write the dfpwm file correctly, having an array of samples and a sample rate.

Thanks

[1]: https://tweaked.cc/library/cc.audio.dfpwm.html#:~:text=DFPWM%20(Dynamic%20Filter%20Pulse%20Width,and%20decode%20in%20real%20time.
[2]: https://github.com/gamax92/LionRay

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest unzipping the computercraft mod.
jar files use the same compression method as zip files and the program to decode/encode dfpwm is an actual program in the rom,
and then that code should be lua and probably more readable.
the folder in the computercraft mod is:
data/computercraft/lua/rom/modules/main/cc/audio/dfpwm.lua
you can also access it with the computercraft filesystem ingame in the rom path.